# Developing for Google App Engine and using the datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I am just getting started with Google Web Toolkit and Google App Engine and have a quick question. I think I understand how to use the datastore now but I was wondering if there is a way that I can quickly create a "database" with static data from an excel sheet? I just need to add some data for a proof of concept later this week.

I am picturing something similar to a SQL database browser where I can just import the data?

I developing in Eclipse with appropriate plugins.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to save your spreadsheet as a CSV file, then use the [bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) to load it into the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to write something to handle uploading it, or to handle processing it on the server.

However, you should also look at the [bulk loader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html).  It might be able to save you a little bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/documents/) is the API (Google Documents List API) that "allows client applications to programmatically access and manipulate user data stored with Google Documents".